# Why am I getting Segmentation Fault when I use differenct input files?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

When I run the code with the first input file the code works fine, but when i use the second input file Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 compiler, shows me the warning: "An Access Violation (Segmentation Fault) raised in your program" pointing to the line:

```
__test = __grouping_tmp[__i] == __grouping[__min];
```

of the file locale_facets.tcc of the compiler. 
I've searched to find possible solutions but nothing came up, can anybody assist me?

Here's My Code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector< vector<int> > adj;
vector <string> towns;
vector <int> w;//weights
vector <int> v;//visited
string town1,town2;
int n,i,j,k,l;

void dfs(int start){
int c,size;
v[start]=1;
size=adj[start].size();
for (c=0;c<size;c++)
   //if ((adj[start][c]==1) && (v[c]==0))
   //if (v[c]==0)
         dfs(adj[start][c]);
}
int findi(string name){ //Finds the I of the town
    for(i=0;i<towns.size();i++){
       if(name==towns[i]){
        return i;
    }
}
return 101;//Dead END
}

int main(){
ifstream fin ("B.in");
ofstream fout ("B.out");

towns.push_back("Start");
w.push_back(0);
bool found;
while(!fin.eof()){
    fin>>town1>>k>>town2>>l;
    found=false;
    for(i=0;i<towns.size();i++){//search an ksanabike i poli
        if(towns[i]==town1){
            found=true;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        towns.push_back(town1);
        w.push_back(k);
    }
}
towns.push_back("Finish");
w.push_back(10001);
for(i=1;i<towns.size()-1;i++){//sorting by weight
    for(j=i+1;j<towns.size();j++){
        if(w[i]>w[j]){
            k=w[i];
            w[i]=w[j];
            w[j]=k;
            town1=towns[i];
            towns[i]=towns[j];
            towns[j]=town1;
        }
    }
}
int c;
string prev;
c=0;
prev=towns[0];
for(i=0;i<towns.size();i++){//sort towns with same weight
    if(towns[i]==prev){
        c++;
    }
    if(towns[i]!=prev&&c!=0){
        sort(towns.begin()+i-c-1,towns.begin()+i-1);
    }
    //Arxikopiisi visited je grafou
    v.push_back(0);
    adj.push_back(vector<int> ());
}
fin.clear();//reset file read!!
fin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
while(!fin.eof()){//Dimiourgia grafou
    fin>>town1>>k>>town2>>l;
    //cout<<town1<<" "<<town2<<endl;
    adj[findi(town1)].push_back(findi(town2));
}
dfs(0);
//cout<<"v size:"<<v.size();
for(i=1;i<towns.size()-1;i++){
    if(v[i]==1){
        fout<<towns[i]<<endl;
    }
}

fin.close();
fout.close();
return 0;
}
```

> > Input file that works-->

Start 0 Larnaca 40

Paphos 70 Finish 10001

Nicosia 90 Finish 10001

Larnaca  40 Paphos 70

Limasol 50 Paphos 70

Limasol 50 Larnaca 40

Nicosia 90 Limasol 50

> > Input File that gives the error -->

Paphos 40 Finish 10001

Nicosia 90 Finish 10001

Start 0 Larnaca 40

Larnaca  40 Paphos 40

Limasol 40 Larnaca 40

Larnaca 40 Limasol 40

Nicosia 90 Limasol 40

Comment: Note: [this `while(!fin.eof())` is **wrong**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Running on gdb it shows an endless recursive call of dfs() function... More exactly is continually running dfs(2) that calls dfs(3) that calls dfs(2)....

Comment: @user3464801 by following [the link in my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) and reading the answers in the posted question.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, it's my first post and I didn't notice the link.

Comment: @user3464801 No worries. and note jsantander's comment. You apparently have an infinite recursion issue in your code. I cannot claim it is due to the double-read of the last input entry, but it certainly isn't helping.

Comment: I found the problem, jsantander was right! Thanks @jsantander, can you recommend any guide to learn how run my programs on gdb?

Comment: @user3464801, I'm afraid I don't have any recommendations. Look at the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/). Googled for cheat sheet and found one that looked [concise enough](http://darkdust.net/files/GDB%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf)... or try running it through an IDE (e.g. Eclipse CDT) or a gui (e.g. [ddd](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/)